# How to fix "unhandled exception has occured in the application" error while launching games like Batman Arkham Asylum

Tags: windows-10, gaming, .net-framework, error-correction

I installed Batman Arkham Asylum from GOG.com. Whenever I try to launch the game, it shows an error "unhandled exception has occured in the .NET Framework."

I have tried rebooting my laptop and reinstalling the game, but to no avail. I also download the latest windows update and it still isn't working.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried the .NET Framework Repair Tool?   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Comment: No I haven't. I will give it a go. Thank you